# dropdown field names in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

For cakephp 1.3, I've created a drop down for birthday like so

```
 echo $form->input('User.birthday', 
            array(

                'label' => __("form_birthday", "true") , 
                'class' => 'date',
                'selected' => 'empty',
                'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
                'minYear' => date('Y') - 90,
                'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18,
                'separator'=> " ",
                'empty' => __("form_select", true),

            )
        );
```

which produces

```
 <div class="input date"><label for="UserBirthdayMonth">Month &amp; Year of      Birth</label><select id="UserBirthdayDay" class="date" name="birthday">
 <option value="">- Select  -</option>
 .....
 </select> <select id="UserBirthdayMonth" class="date" name="birthday">
   <option value="">- Select  -</option>
   <option value="01">January</option>
   <option value="02">February</option>
   <option value="03">March</option>
   <option value="04">April</option>
   <option value="05">May</option>
   <option value="06">June</option>
   <option value="07">July</option>
   <option value="08">August</option>
   <option value="09">September</option>
   <option value="10">October</option>
   <option value="11">November</option>
   <option value="12">December</option>
   </select> <select id="UserBirthdayYear" class="date" name="birthday">
   <option value="">- Select  -</option>
   .....
   </select></div>
```

Notice how the name attribute of the dropdowns are all "birthday". How can I change this in cake so that the name attributes of the three dropdowns above are not all the same? I'd like them be something like "birthday_month", "birthday_year" and "birthday_day".

Comment: Cake should do this automatically. Are those your complete arguments for `input()`? What is `birthday` datatype in the database?

Comment: Did you test the form? I think this is cakephp standards and will save it in your database correctly.

Comment: my `birthday` is of type `date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
echo $this->Form->day('User.birthday', array('empty'=>'Day'));
echo $this->Form->month('User.birthday', array('empty'=>'Month'));
echo $this->Form->year('User.birthday', date('Y')-90 , date('Y') - 18,array('empty'=>'Year'));
```

It will generate same output on post, Kindly ask if not work for you..

Comment: Thanks. This is what I used and it worked. `echo $form->day('User.birthday', array('empty'=>'Day'), array('name'=>'birthday_day'));
echo $form->month('User.birthday', array('empty'=>'Month'),array( 'name'=> 'birthday_month'));
echo $form->year('User.birthday', date('Y')-90 , date('Y') - 18, array('empty'=>'Year'),array( 'name' => 'birthday_year'));`

Comment: I know this is really old... but how can you validate those fields? Normal cakePHP validation doesn't seem to work

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $this->Form->day('User.birthday', array('empty'=>'Day'));
echo $this->Form->month('User.birthday', array('empty'=>'Month'));
echo $this->Form->year('User.birthday', date('Y')-90 , date('Y') - 18,array('empty'=>'Year'));
```